# BotData not saving

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I am trying to create middleware for a firstRun in C# and cant seem to get it to save the data.  Since context is not present in the middleware, I am using the following syntax to save data.  Not only does it not save but I am wondering about the following :

why, when I save in a normal dialog do i have access to SetValue and in here I only have access to SetProperty?

```
public class FirstRunActivityLogger : IActivityLogger
{
    public async Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)
    {
        var allActivity = (Activity)activity;
        StateClient stateClient = allActivity.GetStateClient();
        BotData userData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);
        if (!userData.GetProperty<bool>("FirstRun"))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"From:{activity.From.Id} - To:{activity.Recipient.Id} - Message:{activity.AsMessageActivity()?.Text}");
            userData.SetProperty<bool>("FirstRun", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep in mind that `userData` is just an object and calling `SetProperty()` simply sets property of that object without saving anything. So for saving the bot state you should use `SetUserDataAsync()` and pass that changed `userData` to it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533985/how-to-save-data-of-the-bot-and-reuse-them/42534429#42534429) is how to do it:

```
await stateClient.BotState.SetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, userData);
```